# Determinant of a matrix containing Kronecker deltas

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

Reading de Finetti's "Foresight", I have come across two issues that I do not understand:

1)

$ \begin{vmatrix}
1-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 &\dots & -p_n \\
-p_1 & 1-p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & p_n \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
-p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 & \dots & 1-p_n
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i
 $

I verified the calculation for 1, 2, and 3 dimensions, but failed to generalize the result. Googling, I found that one could use the Kronecker delta in the proof, but how?

2)

Regarding the matrix we are taking the determinant of as coefficient matrix $P$ as a system of linear equations, say $Px = y$, we have $\sum_{i =1}^n p_iy_i = 0$, if the determinant is equal to $0$. Once again, I verified the result for the first three dimensions, but fail to generalize it.

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use column operations: add columns $2$, $3,\ldots ,n$ to column $1$.
Take out the factor $1-\sum_ip_i$ from column $1$. You now have an all-$1$
column. Add $p_j$ times it to column $j$ for $j=2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Very clear! I will need to brush up on LinAlg a little! Would you happen to have a hint as to the second question as well? If not, I'll green-tick your answer, take out the second question, and repost it! Thanks again!

Comment: @MitchBaker Alas, I am not sure I understand your second question $\frown$.